# Error installing RPy2-2.3.8 on Windows 7, Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, rpy2

guys.
I'am trying to installing **RPy2-2.3.8** on **Windows 7** (64bit), **Python 3.3**, but **RPy2** seems to have quite a lot of installation problems...:(

I tried to install RPy2 by typing **"python.exe setup.py install"** on "cmd" on windows environment.

R version 3.0.2 was successfully installed and the path of it was added on environment variable.

However, the following error occurred. Can anybody tell what does this error mean?

```
**D:\>cd rpy2-2.3.8**

D:\rpy2-2.3.8>c:\Python33\python.exe setup.py install
Using 2to3 to translate Python2-only idioms into Python3 code. Please wait...
warning: no previously-included files matching '*patch*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*diff*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.hg' found anywhere in distribution
no previously-included directories found matching 'dist'
done.
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 493, in <module>
    'rpy2': ['doc/source/rpy2_logo.png', ]}
  File "c:\Python33\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "c:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 929, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 948, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\Python33\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 569, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "c:\Python33\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 948, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\Python33\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 947, in run_command
    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "c:\Python33\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "setup.py", line 152, in finalize_options
    rversion = get_rversion(r_home)
  File "setup.py", line 208, in get_rversion
    if rversion.startswith("WARNING"):
**TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str**
```

For me it's especially weird because the error is "TypeError."
Plus, what does all the warnings mean?

All kinds of discussion will be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RPy does not support Python 3.x. You have to use  2.5 <= Python < 3.0. See [official documentation](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/overview.html#requirements) for details.